# MVC3 and TDD pre or post coding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tdd

I am still getting to grips with MVC3, and now I am looking into TDD, and the thing that keeps coming up that makes no sense is.

```
The first step is to quickly add a test, basically just enough code to fail.
```

why create a test for your code to just pass.To me it makes much more sense to write my code then test it and see if it fails, and fix any and all bugs with that may occur then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the test first makes you start thinking about how the method will pass and fail - you start thinking about the method more deeply.

Otherwise, it's easy to get straight into the method without much thought, leading to methods that aren't so easy to test. It's all too easy to come back to the unit-test later - it often doesn't happen!

Moreover, if you write the method first at what point do you write the test? When you know it passes, when you're "happy" with it... It's a slippery slope to writing code without thinking about *testing*.

Comment: I kind of see your point, but if the method was tested as soon as it was complete, then you are still testing the method. And what about the methods/classes etc which once 1/2 way through its then decided to change them completely, the tests you have written would then become redundant adding more time to the project to re write the tests.

Comment: TDD actually helps prevent the changes "1/2 way through" because it makes you think more about the requirements from the beginning. You go back to the business quicker. There is more upfront time to the project - agreed - but I think it is saved longer-term through improved quality. It isn't a silver-bullet, but once you do it you don't like to go back.

Answer (score 2):

If you write the code and then write the tests, then you are not doing **Test-Driven** Development...

That's what TDD stands for; you write your code to enable pre-written tests to pass. If you don't do it that way, you aren't doing TDD.

The idea is that your tests represent your application's requirements. You write those first, just like you would otherwise write your requirements down on paper before you started coding.

This way, you know when all your tests pass, you are done.

Comment: but that would assume that you do not miss any tests and there is no bug in your test that is giving you a positive result when it should be a fail. Also how much more time does TDD add to a project in general?.

Comment: If you miss tests, you aren't doing it right. And if you have bugs in your tests... well... As for how much time does it add; not nearly as much as it saves.